libburn error with xorriso burning blu-ray: Sense Key 5 "Illegal request", ASC 21 ASCQ 04
Every two weeks I make a full backup with zstd compressed tar files:
fileset="10 large files"  # less than 23.1 GB which is the size of formatted BD-RE
xorriso  \
         -for_backup \
         -disk_dev_ino off  \
         -abort_on FATAL     \
         -dev /dev/sr0  \
         -speed 1b  \
         -volid "1_OF_2_20241208"     \
         -report_about ALL  \
         -split_size 2047m  \
         -file_size_limit 23g --  \
         -add $fileset --         \
         -commit  \
         -toc  \
         -check_md5 FAILURE --  

And intermittently there is this error:
libburn : DEBUG : SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): See MMC specs: Sense Key 5 "Illegal request", ASC 21 ASCQ 04.
A fragment of the debug output is this:
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:         32s    0.0%   fifo 100%  buf   0%
libburn : DEBUG : Allocating buffer via mmap()
libburn : NOTE : Write start address is  32 * 2048
libburn : DEBUG : dvd/bd Profile= 43h , obs= 65536 , obs_pad= 0
libburn : DEBUG : Async START UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:        608s    0.0%   fifo 100%  buf   0%    0.4xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:        832s    0.0%   fifo 100%  buf   0%    0.1xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:       3232s    0.0%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    1.1xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:       5344s    0.0%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    1.0xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:       7232s    0.1%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.9xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:       9632s    0.1%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    1.1xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:      11904s    0.1%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    1.0xB
...
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     204032s    1.7%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    1.0xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     206432s    1.7%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    1.1xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     208224s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.8xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     210432s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    1.0xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     212064s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.7xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     212864s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.4xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     212864s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.0xB  # stops writing *****
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     212864s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.0xB
...
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     212864s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.0xB
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     212864s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.0xB
libisofs: DEBUG : Reader thread being cancelled
libisofs: MISHAP : Image write cancelled
libisofs: DEBUG : Writer thread joined
libburn : DEBUG : SCSI error condition on command 2Ah WRITE(10): See MMC specs: Sense Key 5 "Illegal request", ASC 21 ASCQ 04.
libburn : DEBUG : CDB= 2a 00 00 03 3f 80 00 00 20 00  : dxfer_len= 65536
libburn : FATAL : SCSI error on write(212864,32): See MMC specs: Sense Key 5 "Illegal request", ASC 21 ASCQ 04.
libburn : FATAL : CDB= WRITE(10) : 2a 00 00 03 3f 80 00 00 20 00  : dxfer_len= 65536
libburn : DEBUG : syncing cache
xorriso : FATAL : -abort_on 'FATAL' encountered 'FATAL' during image writing
xorriso : NOTE : libburn has now been urged to cancel its operation
xorriso : UPDATE : Writing:     212864s    1.8%   fifo 100%  buf 100%    0.0xB
libburn : DEBUG : Async SYNCHRONIZE CACHE  succeeded after 0.1 seconds
libburn : DEBUG : Write thread on drive 0 ended
xorriso : DEBUG : burn_set_signal_handling(256)
libisofs: DEBUG : Reader thread being cancelled
xorriso : FAILURE : libburn indicates failure with writing.
libisofs: DEBUG : Ring buffer was 6653 times full and 0 times empty
xorriso : aborting : -abort_on 'FATAL' encountered 'FATAL'
libburn : DEBUG : Async STOP UNIT succeeded after 0.1 seconds
xorriso backup to BD failed.  xorriso exit status is 5

The BD drive is an ASUS BW-16D1HT revision 3.11
The BD-RE Verbatim disc is formatted with "xorriso -dev /dev/sr0 -format by_index_3" and has 23.1 GB free.
I have made succesfull backups for 10 months and then problems started.
Using new blank Verbatim discs did not help.
I tried an LG BH16NS55 but that did not help.
What is the cause of this issue ?
How to fix it ?

The sense code ASC 21 ASCQ 04 is not supposed to come from an optical
drive. According to https://www.t10.org/lists/asc-num.htm#ASC_21 it
means "UNALIGNED WRITE COMMAND". (Note the missing "R" which would
indicate that the code applies to optical drives.)
I fail to imagine what kind of alignment a drive with a BD-RE could
demand and not get fulfilled by block address 0x33f80 = 212864 and
write chunk size 0x20 = 32 blocks = 64 KiB.
So this does not look like a drive or medium problem.
Can it be that the bus hardware to which your drives get attached is
becoming flaky and generates synthetic SCSI error codes (or instigates
the kernel to produce 21 04) ?
How were the two drives connected to the computer ? USB ? SATA ?
Same sockets for the data cable ?

The drives were mounted with the same new internal SATA cable.  I do not recall if I used a different socket - probably not.

The ubuntu 24.04 system was just rebooted and now the issue is gone.  I have read somewhere that a reboot may resolve this.  Next time this issue occurs I will try a device removal/scan instead of a reboot.
